# What happens to running Java processes when you restart the python kernel with a running jpype JVM?

Tags: python, jvm, jpype

I'm using JPype1==1.2.1 and python==3.6.2 to use java functionalities from an external source, which involves logging in to servers, listening to events etc.

As the jpype.shutdownJVM() routine hangs when called, I don't use that, but I restart the kernel to get a fresh session.

I'm new to java, but would restarting the kernel and spinning up a new JVM with jpype.startJVM() result in a fresh session with no legacy from earlier sessions? Not sure what happens on the java side.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: restart and see what happens

Comment: Thats the point, I dont know what is happening on the JVM side.